# JavaScript Преобразование чисел при вычислениях

Tags: javascript

Всем привет. Столкнулся с такой странностью при вычислениях. Если такая тема уже была, буду рад ссылкам.
Есть скрипт, в котором выполняется такое выражение i*1024*1024. Так вот, если значение этого выражения меньше, чем
**100000000000**, или больше чем **999999999999**, то число получается правильное. Но если значение попадает в этот "волшебный" диапазон, результат может быть такой:

```
95368*1024*1024 = 100000595967.:
95369*1024*1024 = 100001644543.:
95370*1024*1024 = 10000269311:
95371*1024*1024 = 100003741696
```

Т.е. некоторые значения получаются правильными, а у некоторых появляются точка, двоеточие. Понятно, что в таком случае возникает ошибка.
Предвижу вопрос: JavaScript не самой свежей редакции. Читал ECMA 262-3 §9.8.1, там что-то описывается про преобразование чисел, но не до конца понятно, как это происходит. Может кто-нибудь привести пару примеров.
Но в любом случае, с чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Где именно это выполняется? В консоли хрома всё правильно считается.

Comment: В приложении используется SpiderMonkey 1.8.5, т.е. движок очень старый.

Comment: JohnDoe вообще не понятно как такой результат выходит но по идее parseInt должен решить проблему parseInt(123abraKatabra) => 123

Comment: parseInt только обрежет нецифры, но проблема в том, что разряд единиц считается неправильно, например 95370*1024*1024 = 10000269311: хотя должно быть 100002693120. Странно, что проблема с отображением чисел длиной 12 цифр, если цифр 11 или 13 - все правильно.